# Automatically selected Radiobutton tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to make a choice menu with Radiobutton using `*kwargs`.
Unfortunately the sent variable order is not kept as wished for: Easy, Medium, Hard, Extreme. And, even though I did set v to a specific value, all the choices are selected at once.

Am I missing something here?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

    def onClick(self, event):
        print("Clicked")

    def qChoice(self, **kwargs):
        v = IntVar()
        v.set(1)
        for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            self.Rbutton = Radiobutton(text=key, variable=v, value=value)
            self.Rbutton.grid(sticky=W)

    def basics(self):
        self.label = Label(text="Enter name:")
        self.label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="E")
        self.entry = Entry()
        self.entry.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.button = Button(text="Enter")
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>", self.onClick)
        self.button.grid(column=3, row=0)
        self.qChoice(Easy=1,Medium=2,Hard=3,Extreme=4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App = MainApplication(root)
    App.basics()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a local variable for `v` which is getting garbage collected when the function exits. You need to keep a permanent reference:

```
def qChoice(self, **kwargs):
    self.v = Intvar()
    ...
```

---

On a side note, you don't need both import statements. Use one or the other, but not both. Ideally, use the first one:

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't even see it that way.
Do you have any idea why the *kwargs are not correctly iterated ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `IntVar()` is local and is garbaged.

```
def qChoice(self, **kwargs):
    # changed to self.v from v
    self.v = IntVar()
    # .set(None) leaves all the self.v instances blank
    # if you did .set('1'), the first one will be auto-selected
    # you can also remove this line if you want them to start blank
    self.v.set(None)
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        self.Rbutton = Radiobutton(text=key, variable=self.v, value=value)
        self.Rbutton.grid(sticky=W)
```

Similar topics for you:

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684739/why-do-tkinters-radio-buttons-all-start-selected-when-using-stringvar-but-not-i)

[Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199086/tkinter-radiobutton-gets-selected-when-the-mouse-hovers-over-it)